# PC boot: dl register and drive number

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader, x86-16, bios

I read somewhere in the internet that, before jumping to 0x7c00, the BIOS loads into %dl the "drive number" of the booted device. But what is this "drive number"? Each device attached to the computer is assigned a number by the BIOS? If so, how can I know which number is a given device assigned to?

Reading GRUB's source code I found when %dl has bits 0x80 and 0x70 set, it overwrites the whole register with 0x80. Why is that? Here is the code:

```
jmp 3f      /* grub-setup may overwrite this jump */
testb $0x80, %dl
jz 2f
3:
/* Ignore %dl different from 0-0x0f and 0x80-0x8f.  */
testb $0x70, %dl
jz 1f
2:     
movb $0x80, %dl
1:
```

By the way. Is there any detailed resource on the boot process of PC's in the web? Specially about what the BIOS does before giving the control to the bootloader and also the standard codes used to communicate with it (like that "drive numer"). I was hoping to write my own bootloader and everything I found is a bit too vague, not technical enough to the point of informing of the exact state of the computer when my bootloader starts to run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BIOS int 13h functions accept a drive number. It's supposed to be that kind of drive number in `DL`, the one BIOS understands, because, well, it itself uses int 13h to load boot sectors.

Comment: Ok. I know the bios understands it, but I want to understand too. :) What I want to know is how are these codes assigned. Like, if they are static (0 for a given device, 1 for another... etc) and if so, where can I get this list; and if they are not, how does the bios assign them.

Comment: AFAIK, 0x80 is the only valid drive number for the boot hard drive, similarly 0x00 for the boot floppy drive. There's this comment in the code: `This is a workaround for buggy BIOSes which don't pass boot drive correctly. If GRUB is installed into a HDD, check if DL is masked correctly. If not, assume that the BIOS passed a bogus value and set DL to 0x80, since this is the only possible boot drive. If GRUB is installed into a floppy, this does nothing (only jump).` That's how it's been traditionally. Non-boot drive numbers are higher.

Comment: I see. Will it be the same number (0x80) for flash and cd-rom drives?

Comment: If you boot from there, it should be 0x80.